# Add url parameter to redirect function in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am having an issue with redirect function in codeignitor.

I have the following code

```
redirect('register/?id='.$post["id"]); // It works
```

But when I do

```
redirect('register/'.$post["id"]);  // Then it says page missing.
```

The register page is there but it's not understanding the url parameter.I am not sure if it is htaccess issue or framework issue.

htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use mod_rewrite? Please show your rewrite rule, then. If you use a framework, tell us the name of it

Comment: The framework name is there in my question.I am using pyrocms which is built on codeignitor and  there is a htaccess file.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. It was my fault. I didn't read it correctly.

Comment: np..I have added the htaccess code. Thanks.

Comment: are you redirecting to `index` function of `register` controller ? @Raj

Comment: Yes Karan.The redirect is written under controller which is redirecting to index.

Comment: you need to use `redirect('register/index/'.$post["id"]);` instead of `redirect('register/'.$post["id"]);` @Raj

Comment: Thanks.I used index but still going to page missing.